# Ajax Request Data Undefined/Failing for one specific computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

*SEE UPDATE

I am facing an issue that has me stumped.  Basically, when a user clicks on a link, a form opens in a jquery ui modal dialog box and it also triggers an ajax request to pull necessary data for the form.  The issue that i'm facing is that when on computer A/B/C etc it works w/o issue, however when on computer Z (of course computer Z is my project manager's computer ;D ) the ajax request is either never sent or the data returned is undefined (can't access his computer right now to verify - I believe the ajax call completes successfully but the data is undefined).  Of course, this leads to the form not being able to be submit as the required data that it pulls (or fails to pull) is undefined.

My question is what would be potentially causing this? Computer Z has only tried using Chrome.  Caches have been cleared, browser restarted, JavaScript is enabled, CORS headers have been set.  This action works fine on Chrome from other computers.

Computer Z was able to perform the same action (submit the form) that's causing the error last week and no changes were made to the ajax calls (and it is currently working on all other computers tested)

I can post the code if necessary/requested but since it's working on the other computers I'm not initially and am instead interested in just gathering potential causes.

I'm running out of ideas.  Please help :)  Much appreciated.

**UPDATE - I was able to go ahead and hop onto his computer (computer Z) w/ my user credentials and everything worked as expected.  Is there any kind of setting at the user account level (windows 10) to cause this difference? That appears to me to be the only difference in the environments at this point.

Comment: I think you've knocked on the wrong door, this is _not_ the annual clairvoyants meeting. On a more serious note, sit in front of Computer Z and start debugging! Having people here shoot in the dark is rather pointless.

Comment: @ndm haha - I can't until Monday, otherwise thats exactly where I would be! was really just looking for a brainstorm to gather possibilities so I can let them marinate over the weekend :)

Comment: Yeah, I get that, and I understand your motives, it's just that in this form, such a question is offtopic on StackOverflow, as it's kinda open-ended, not reproducable, and more of a chat (until monday maybe, when you can start investigating the problem).

Comment: @ndm yeah for sure. I was actually able to get into his office to test on computer Z using my user account (check update) and all worked...so i'm even more perplexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, it appears to be related to the user account being used in Windows 10.  When I was able to successfully submit on computer Z, I was not logged in as an admin.  When my supervisor/project manager was logged in computer Z and not able to post/submit the form, he was logged in as an admin.  We believe that it was caused because of a new security feature restricting/discouraging normal user operations from admin accounts in Windows 10 (my supervisor can't even open Microsoft Edge - their new web browser while logged in as an admin).  The admin/non-admin appears to be what's causing it as we've successfully submitted from computer Z using non-admin accounts other than mine as well.

Thank you all for your help/suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Computer Z could be behind a firewall. Try making an identical request from a REST client on computer Z to see if that makes it through, there are some Chrome extensions that will do it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be happening. We'll need more information to diagnose it but you can try checking any proxies, antivirus, or firewalls that might be enabled.

In Chrome you can check proxies at chrome://net-internals/#proxy

If it isn't a network issue then it could be a race condition in your application. Try adding some sort of delay into your application that would figure out where the race condition could be happening.

Lastly, make sure you try to use incognito mode in chrome to ensure that no extensions are interfering with the page.